# What's keyword about repeat $addtoset in mongodb by mongoskin ( I read english a little)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

Sorry, I can't find answer and I can't read english.

What's keyword can find answer about the following example code ?

```
for(var value in row){
db.collection('testdb').update({_id:'id'},{$addToSet:value},                                                                            
   { upsert: true },function(err){}
)
value.empty();
```

}

I don't know why  my code can't work

```
testdb: { "_id" : "id", "v" : [v1], "p" : [ p1] }
```

after repeat update

```
{ "_id" : "id", "v" : [v1,p2], "p" : [ p1,p2] }
```

but should be

```
{ "_id" : "id", "v" : [v1,v2], "p" : [ p1,p2] }
```

to Neil Lunn

```
row count = 2 ;
row[0] = { "v" : [v2] }
row[1] = { "p" : [p2] }
```

to  Farid Nouri Neshat

```
app.post('index',function(req,res){

    var doc =[];
    var d ={};
    var e ={}
    for(var value in req.body){            
        d[value]=doc;                
        e['$each']=doc;
        d[value]=e;               
        db.collection('testdb').update({_id:req.body.field},{$addToSet:d},                                       
           { upsert: true },function(err){})                                            
        doc=[];//clear doc
        d={};//clear d
        }
    }
 // req.body.count = 2
 // req.body[0] = { "v" : [v2] }
 // req.body[1] = { "p" : [p2] }

  }
```

Comment: What are you passing in as `value`? You have two arrays (sets) in here and you are not showing us that part of your statement.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each

Comment: There's not enough information in here. If the row is `[{ v: [v2], p : [p2] }]` then nothing is wrong here. Share more code. Post a minimal example that can be run on our computers locally showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code you posted doesn't replicate the problem. But judging from the fact that both `p` and `v` arrays, got the last value, It looks like, that you are running update method in a callback in the for loop, so when the update method is run, the key is already changed to the last key. You can read more about the problem in this question: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/774086)

What I suggest you to try is to instead of using `for(var value in req.body) {` change that using Object.keys:

```
Object.keys(req.body).forEach(function (value) {
    // Do whatever you do inside the loop in here.
});
```

This will capture `value` argument and it won't change on the next iterations. I have explained this in a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23670936/774086).

Comment: very very thank you , the problem confused me long time

Comment: OK!  nice to meet you !